# Calculate Type of the member in a table (Self Join/Case When or any other possible way)

Tags: sql-server, join, recursion, ssms

Here is the Table :

```
If OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..##SelfCount') Is not null
    drop table #SelfCount

create table #SelfCount (CanID int , CanType int)

insert into #SelfCount (CanID, CanType)
values
(1,0),
(2,0),
(1,1),
(2,1),
(1,2),
(1,2),
(1,0)

CanID   CanType     
1             0     
2             0     
1             1     
2             1     
1             2     
1             2     
1             0
```

I'm Expecting the result to be like this

```
CanID   Self    Spouse  Dependent
1         2       1         2
2         1       1         0/NULL --It doesn't matter if it's nUll or 0
```

I wrote this query

```
select  CanID, 
        case 
        When CanType = 0 then count(CanType) 
        end as [self],
        case 
        when CanType = 1 then count(CanType)
        end as [Spouse],
        Case 
        When CanType = 2 then count(CanType)
        end as [Dependent]
from #SelfCount
Group by CanID, CanType
```

But the Result Set is like this :

```
CanID   Self   Spouse     Dependent
1       2       NULL        NULL
2       1       NULL        NULL
1       NULL    1           NULL
2       NULL    1           NULL
1       NULL    NULL        2
```

I've tried the Recursive method, If anyone could provide both Recursive as well as Set processing method, it'll be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should we guess how you did get those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By including the `CanType` in the `group by` clause, you're getting a separate result row per distinct value of `CanType` (and `CanId`, since it's also contained in the `group by` clause).

Instead, you should only have `CanId` in the `group by` clause, and apply different `count`s on `case` expressions:

```
SELECT   CanID, 
         COUNT (CASE CanType WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) AS [Self], 
         COUNT (CASE CanType WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS [Spouse], 
         COUNT (CASE CanType WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS [Dependent], 
FROM     #SelfCount
GROUP BY CanID
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you need:

```
select CanID, 
       sum(case when CanType = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as [Self],
       sum(case when CanType = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Spouse],
       sum(case when CanType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [Dependent]
from #SelfCount
group by CanID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **PIVOT**:

```
select 
  CanID, 
  [0] as Self, 
  [1] as Spouse, 
  [2] as Dependent 
from tab
pivot
(
  count (CanType)
  for CanType IN ([0], [1], [2])
) as pvt
```

Basically, it will group by all columns not declared inside the **PIVOT** clause (actually, just the CanID) and then create three aggregation **COUNT** columns, one **FOR** each CanType **IN** the list of values. If you need to count more values, just define them in the **IN** clause and in the **SELECT** clause.

Comment: Even this solution worked like charm, thank u so much